# Why does this closure require inlining or `dyn`? What does `dyn` do here?

Tags: lambda, rust, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm confused about what's going on with lifetimes below:

```rust
struct Foo{}
impl Foo {
    fn foo(&self, _s: &str) {}
}

fn main() {
    let foo = &Foo{};
    let closure = |s| foo.foo(s);

    // Part 1: error message about wrong lifetime in FnOnce
    take_closure(closure); 

    // Part 2: no error when inlined
    take_closure(|s| foo.foo(s));

    // Part 3: no error when `dyn`d and given explicit signature
    let closure: &dyn Fn(&str) -> _ = &|s| foo.foo(s);
    take_closure(closure);
}

fn take_closure(f: impl Fn(&str) -> ()) {
    let s = get_string();
    f(&s)
}

fn get_string() -> String {
    "".to_string()
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f7c25460d5b19739eb3b1633d98189f9)

1. Why does Part 1 error?
2. Why does Part 2 not error?
3. Why does Part 3 not error and what actually happens in part 3? Does Rust make a vtable? The LLVM outputs differ between 2 and 3
4. Is there a better way? Inlining is ugly and `dyn` is both ugly and makes me wonder about what it actually does.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696907/why-does-passing-a-closure-to-function-which-accepts-a-function-pointer-not-work

Comment: @EricMagers That question is about function pointers, not closures

Comment: Parts of this question are answered at [Expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31362206/3650362), [How to declare a higher-ranked lifetime for a closure argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31403723/3650362), and [Returning a higher-kinded closure that captures a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69048869/3650362).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does Part 1 error?

Rust's type inference is not great at deciding what type a closure should have, when the closure is declared separately from where it is used. When the closure accepts references, the compiler often assumes that there is some *specific* lifetime that will be involved, not “any lifetime the caller cares to provide” as is actually required here.

In fact, there's [an active Rust RFC to improve this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3216) by adding another way to specify lifetime parameters on closures. (The RFC also contains an example where making the opposite lifetime assumption would not work.)

> what actually happens in part 3? Does Rust make a vtable?

Yes, there's a vtable involved whenever you use `dyn`. That's not especially relevant to the root cause here; it's just that the elided lifetime in `dyn Fn(&str)` got resolved the way you needed rather than the way you didn't.

> Is there a better way? Inlining is ugly and `dyn` is both ugly and makes me wonder about what it actually does.

Placing a closure directly in the function call expression that uses it is *very* common Rust style, and I recommend you stick to it whenever possible, since it's also the way that works well with type inference.

As a workaround in the case where you need to use a closure more than once, you could pass the closure through a function that constrains its type:

```rust
fn string_acceptor<F: Fn(&str) -> ()>(f: F) -> F {
    f
}

...

    let foo = &Foo{};
    let closure = string_acceptor(|s| foo.foo(s));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the idea for using an intermediate function.
Why does the `dyn` example work? Does `dyn` make the closure a trait object, so something here explains it? https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes

Comment: Is there any performance implication to `dyn`ifying the closure?

Comment: @MaxHeiber I don't have a good general explanation for how lifetimes are chosen. "Does dyn make the closure a trait object": yes. "so something here explains it?": not that section, that's about the lifetime of state _held by the closure_, not of its arguments. See [lifetime elision in functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/lifetime-elision.html#lifetime-elision-in-functions) instead. "Is there any performance implication to `dyn`ifying the closure?" Certainly, but beware of assuming that it's significant.